# How to modify function parameter objects for dynamically defined class

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of draw functions that take their parameters as objects.

```js
const draw = {
  pixel({ ctx, x, y }) { /* ... */ },
  // ...many more functions...
}

draw.pixel({ ctx, x: 1, y: 1 }) // usage example
```

Because `ctx` is a required parameter for all these functions and often doesn't change, I've created a wrapper class where you set `ctx` once and then it's automatically passed along.

```js
const drawer = new Drawer(ctx) // create drawer with associated ctx

drawer.pixel({ x: 1, y: 1 }) // no need for ctx here
```

I don't want to explicitly define the `Drawer` class since I'd just be repeating myself, so I've dynamically added each `draw` method to the `Drawer` prototype. It works fine but TypeScript hates it (understandably).

```js
class Drawer {
  constructor(ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx
  }
  // methods added below...
}

// for each method name of draw
Object.keys(draw).forEach(key => {
  // create a method on Drawer with the same name
  Drawer.prototype[key] = function (args={}) {
    // that calls the underlying draw method using Drawer's ctx
    return draw[key]({ ctx: this.ctx, ...args })
  }
})
```

**Question:** How can I convince TypeScript that the `Drawer` class has all the same methods as the `draw` object literal, the only difference being a specific property within each function's parameter object? (And is there a better way to do this?)

Notably, I've figured out how to remove function parameters if they're separate:

```
type FuncAB = (a: number, b: number) => void
type FuncB = FuncAB extends (a: number, ...args: infer T) => void ? (...args: T) => void : never
// FuncB: (b: number) => void
```

But I still can't manipulate properties within a function parameter object:

```
type FuncAB = ({ a, b }: { a: number, b: number }) => void
type FuncB = ???
// FuncB: ({ b: number }) => void
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You might be looking for `Omit` or the equivalent.  I fleshed out one possibility [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WkDvlw); does that work how you want?  If so I could write up an answer explaining how it works. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you that works perfectly. I'll happily accept your answer when you write it. Looking forward to the explanation.